# Find image within image vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, opencv, bitmap, emgucv

I am trying to find the location of an image within a bigger image. I have wasted about 6-7 hours resourcing and couldn't manage to come up with something that I could use.
I looked into

- OpenCV ([Website Link](https://opencv.org/))
- Emgu ([Website Link](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page))
- Bitmap.contains ([Thread link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899828/vb-net-check-if-image-existing-in-another-image))
- Bitmap.contains 2 ([Thread link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872079/searching-a-rectangle-on-the-screen-for-and-comparing-to-an-image-imagesearchin))

All the tutorials I have found in Emgu is really outdated (For the VBS). I even downloaded the older version of the dlls to make the script work but yet not quite right. The bitmap.contains one looked pretty interesting but for some reason it's not working.

Here are the pictures I am working with:

1. [Main Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rot6I.png)
2. [Sub Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gKKC.png)

Any help would be really appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: The bitmap one works, but if I make the sub image smaller or transparent it cant detect.

Comment: [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=matchtemplate#cv2.matchTemplate) `matchTemplate` method does what you want. You also have its equivalent on [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/ee43f981-70ee-04c2-4c10-764da38f0781.htm).